# is there a shortcut to send a window to background in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is there any way to send a single window to the back in Windows 7, so that it is under all of the other windows?

There is an application called "Send to back" that worked fine in Windows XP, but doesn't seem to do the job in Windows 7.

Comment: Why would you wanna do that, in stead of just activating the window you need using alt-tab?

Comment: @fretje: because I have 50 windows open, and I know the one I want is right behind the one on top.

Comment: @grawity: I have never been able to make sense of the Alt+Tab list.

Comment: The reason this is important to me: pressing Alt-Esc repeatedly cycles through my maximized windows, which Alt-Tab does not.

Comment: minimizing is very convenient but it also sucks for some things, so sending a window to the back (behind your other on-screen windows), is an alternative - so that's a good reason... example of thing that it sucks for is videos, or anything that updates the screen without user input - like charts... if you press `alt` or `start tab` to have a peek, you see ***stale data***... _when minimized_, when _sent to back_, the windows keep _chugging along_... if anyone knows a way to _minimize and still have the windows update themselves_, please let me know.. even registry hacks would be acceptable

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: can I move it to another key?

Comment: Alt-Esc does **not always** send the focused window to the bottom of the z-order stack in Windows 7.  It is meant to cycle through the windows in the order they were opened.  It might send the current window all the way to the bottom.  Or it might not.  Haven't exactly figured out the pattern.

Comment: Hey cool, this still works in Windows 10! Thanks.

Comment: @BobStein, i think it sends the window to the bottom of the opened and not minimized windows stack.