# Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut to restore a previous window layering arrangement? (in Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I guess the answer is no, but it would be so useful that I want to make sure. Here is a scenario: I have a three windows open on my monitor: a terminal, my email app, and a web browser. I have the email app and terminal arranged next to each other, and the web browser is underneath them. Say I want to look something up: I click on an exposed part of the web browser to bring it to the top, do my searching, and then I want to send it back to the bottom layer. Currently, I would have to highlight both the terminal AND the email app to bring them each to the front one after the other.

So the question: is there instead a way to just send the web browser to the bottom (not minimising it, just changing its visibility layer)? Or more generally, is there a way to restore the layering arrangement of a bunch of windows to a previous state? I feel like I could avoid a lot of unnecessary moving/clicking of my mouse if something like this was possible.

Edit: A little similar to this question for Windows 7, though there is no solution there: [is there a shortcut to send a window to background in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/242967/is-there-a-shortcut-to-send-a-window-to-background-in-windows-7)

Comment: With AutoHotkey and scripts possibilities are unlimited>>>>https://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: You can create lots of shortcuts in various ways, but restoring a dynamic layout to a prior layout version is not really possible. Otherwise lots of ways for shortcuts and productivity as I posted and the earlier SU answer pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Windowing (open Window Layout) is dynamic and always changing so the answer to your question is: No.  You cannot restore a dynamic layout.

What I do (and I have your issues as well) is ensure that my apps are set (Windows Settings) to have one icon for all that apps Windows in the taskbar.

Having done that, I can hover over the task bar and select. I am heading to a meeting (Zoom), have Word, Adobe, Web Browser and 3 VMs are running and another PC beside me whose job it is to have the meeting documents open. This can be done with a second screen.

So while you cannot do as you wish, there are a lot of productivity tools in Windows 10 to be very productive and not lose time.

One possibility for you is to use Virtual Desktop with different Window Layouts on each Virtual Desktop. These are available with a single mouse click.

Virtual Desktops CONS:  You have to set them up (not automatic) and they go away with each shutdown / restart. But they do work.